# Calculate difftime by group over non-consecutive rows with conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, difftime

I'm trying to create a new variable representing the time lapsed from the "rare_event" until the next "common_event" grouped by "id".

Here is some code:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep("A",10), rep("B",10), rep("C",10)), 
                 time = c(rep(seq(1:10),3)),
                 common_event = c(rep(0, 3), 1, rep(0, 3), 1, rep(0, 5), 1, rep(0, 5), 1, rep(0, 3), 1, rep(0, 2), 1, rep(0, 2), 1),
                 rare_event = c(rep(0, 5), 1, rep(0, 3), 1, rep(0, 6), 1, rep(0, 7), 1, 1, rep(0, 3), 1))
```

I thought it'd be easier, but there are some issues:

1. Not every "id" will have "rare_event" == TRUE.
2. Some "id" will have more than one "rare_event" before the next "common_event", like rows 25, 26.

I tried using for loop and lead and lag from dplyr, but I had no success.

Here is the desired result:

```
desired <- data.frame(id = c(rep("A",10), rep("B",10), rep("C",10)), 
                 time = c(rep(seq(1:10),3)),
                 common_event = c(rep(0, 3), 1, rep(0, 3), 1, rep(0, 5), 1, rep(0, 5), 1, rep(0, 3), 1, rep(0, 2), 1, rep(0, 2), 1),
                 rare_event = c(rep(0, 5), 1, rep(0, 3), 1, rep(0, 6), 1, rep(0, 7), 1, 1, rep(0, 3), 1),
                 interval = c(rep(0, 5), 2, rep(0, 10), 3, rep(0, 7), 2, 1, rep(0, 4)))
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: why raw 17 has 4 not 3? and raw 25  has 2 not 1?

Comment: You are right. My mistake. Row 17 is 3, not 4. row 25 is 2 because it counts two-time intervals until the next common_event.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way, but this seems to work.

First, define a function, foo, that does the work.

```
foo <- function(time, common, rare) {
  interval <- rep(0, length(time))
  time_comm <- time*common
  for (t in time) {
    if(rare[t]==1) {
      # Find the next time when a common event occurred, if any
      if(any(time>t & common==1)) {
        t_comm <- min(time_comm[time>t & common==1])
        interval[t] <- t_comm - t
      }
      }
  }
  interval
}
```

---

Then, apply this function to each id of the data frame, f:

```
library(dplyr)
f %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(interval=foo(time, common_event, rare_event))
```

---

Output:

```
   id time common_event rare_event interval
1   A    1            0          0        0
2   A    2            0          0        0
3   A    3            0          0        0
4   A    4            1          0        0
5   A    5            0          0        0
6   A    6            0          1        2
7   A    7            0          0        0
8   A    8            1          0        0
9   A    9            0          0        0
10  A   10            0          1        0

11  B    1            0          0        0
12  B    2            0          0        0
13  B    3            0          0        0
14  B    4            1          0        0
15  B    5            0          0        0
16  B    6            0          0        0
17  B    7            0          1        3
18  B    8            0          0        0
19  B    9            0          0        0
20  B   10            1          0        0

21  C    1            0          0        0
22  C    2            0          0        0
23  C    3            0          0        0
24  C    4            1          0        0
25  C    5            0          1        2
26  C    6            0          1        1
27  C    7            1          0        0
28  C    8            0          0        0
29  C    9            0          0        0
30  C   10            1          1        0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Edward. Quite a complicated function you wrote here, but it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry I couldn't make it less complicated, but I think the complexity matches the task! The last id "C" (consecutive rare_events) made things tricky.